# Upgrade from 16.04 to 18.04.1 won't work because of authorisation issues

Tags: 16.04, upgrade, 18.04

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 at work, and would like to upgrade to 18.04.

```
$ uname -a
Linux superbock 4.15.0-34-generic #37~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Aug 28 10:44:06  UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

When I get the upgrade windows as follows:

[image]

I click on `Upgrade...` but nothing happens.

I tried running the update manager on the command line using

```
$ update-manager
```

When I click `Update...`, it says on the console

> Error checking for authorization com.ubuntu.release-upgrader.release-upgrade: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Message recipient disconnected from message bus without replying

I also tried using the `do-release-upgrade` command:

```
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt upgrade
$ sudo apt dist-upgrade
$ sudo apt-get autoremove
$ sudo apt install update-manager-core
$ sudo do-release-upgrade
```

And I get the following :

```
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Get:1 Upgrade tool signature [819 B]                                                                                                                               
Get:2 Upgrade tool [1,258 kB]                                                                                                                                      
Fetched 1,259 kB in 0s (0 B/s)                                                                                                                                     
authenticate 'bionic.tar.gz' against 'bionic.tar.gz.gpg' 
gpg exited 1
Debug information: 


gpg: Signature made Wed 29 Aug 2018 19:33:13 BST using RSA key ID C0B21F32
gpg: /tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-ahhadl1h/trustdb.gpg: trustdb created
gpg: BAD signature from "Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key (2012) <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>"

Authentication failed
Authenticating the upgrade failed. There may be a problem with the network or with the server.
```

Not sure what is going on? Could someone advise on how to get this sorted?

Comment: Could it be something similar to this https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2068667 ?

Comment: @Terrance Seems to have worked, I do not get the error any more. I will run it on Monday though as I won't have time to make the upgrade tonight before going home.

Comment: @Terrance I managed to successfully run the upgrade today thanks to the link you provided. I wrote an answer explaining it. Cheers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to Terrance comment in my original post, I managed to fix it. The problem was that `gb.archive.ubuntu.com` was not accessible.

It is configured here (the drop down saying **Server for United Kingdom**):
[image]

It would not allow me to change it to be the **Main server**. Even running the `update-manager` as root so I had to do it manually in the `/etc/apt/sources.list` file.

Once replacing all the occurrences of `http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com` by `http://archive.ubuntu.com` in `/etc/apt/sources.list` the update manager is now set to the **Main server** download source:

[image]

After that, the update goes on with no issues.

Comment: Ran into nearly the same issue a few minutes ago, while updating a Ubuntu LTS 16.04.x server to 18.04 using `do-release-upgrade`. I used the official german mirror, after striping every `de.` from `/etc/apt/sources.list`, I did not run into any trouble anymore.